# bad alloc exception when trying to resolve BFS challenge on HackerRank

Tags: c++, exception, out-of-memory, breadth-first-search, bad-alloc

So i was trying to make the challage: Breadth First Search: Shortest Reach on HackerRank, but i keep getting the bad alloc exception when the tests have great numbers of node/edges. The program works on the first test, so i don't think, it's something wrong with the implementation.
So here is the implementation:
(sorry for the indentation , my first question)

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
//test numbers
int t;
//the cost
int cost = 6;
cin >> t;
//for each test
for (int nt = 0; nt < t; ++nt) {
    int n, e;
    int snode;
    queue <int> *que = new queue<int>();
    //read the node/edges
    cin >> n >> e;
    //distance/visited/parents arrays/adjlist vector
    int dist[n + 1] = {-1};
    bool visited[n + 1] = {false};
    int parents[n + 1] = {-1};
    vector< vector<int> > adjList(n + 1);

    //read into the adjlist, unoriented graph, each edge has 6 weight
    for (int ne = 0; ne < e; ++ne) {
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        adjList[x].push_back(y);
        adjList[y].push_back(x);
    }

    //read the starting node
    cin >> snode;
    dist[snode] = 0;

    //do actual bfs
    que->push(snode);
    visited[snode] = true;
    while(!que->empty()) {
        int c_node = que->front();
        que->pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < adjList[c_node].size(); ++i) {
            if (visited[adjList[c_node].at(i)] == false) {
                que->push(adjList[c_node].at(i));
                parents[adjList[c_node].at(i)] = c_node;
                dist[adjList[c_node].at(i)] = dist[parents[adjList[c_node].at(i)]] + cost;
                visited[adjList[c_node].at(i)] == true;
            }
        }
    }

    //print at output the distance from the starting node to each other node
    //if unreachable, print -1
    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; ++i) {
        if (i == snode) {

        } else if (dist[i] == 0 && i != snode) {
            cout << "-1 ";
        } else {
            cout << dist[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

Am i doing something wrong, i haven't seen anyone else complain on this matter in the discussion section of the site.
How can i avoid the exception to be thrown and from where does it come?
Thank you!

Comment: Edit: the problem was at
    visited[adjList[c_node].at(i)] == true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, exactly, what is the cause of your exception; and I don't know ho to reproduce your problem because depends (I suppose) from the input values. A lot of input values, I suppose.

But I see some weak points (IMHO) of your code, so I try to point your attention to them.

1) you alloc a `std::queue` in your `for` cycle

```
queue <int> *que = new queue<int>();
```

but you never free it; it's a waste of memory

2) you're using C-style variable-length arrays

```
int dist[n + 1] = {-1};
bool visited[n + 1] = {false};
int parents[n + 1] = {-1};
```

They aren't valid C++ standard code. I suggest you the use of standard containers (`std::vector` or `std::queue`).

3) you're initializing your C-style variable-length arrays with a initializers lists with only an element (`-1` or `false`). I suppose your intention was initialize all `n+1` elements with `-1` and `false`. But this syntax initialize only the first element of the array with `-1` and `false`.

If you want to initialize all `n+1` element to `-1` and `false`, the solution is (again) use standard containers; by example

```
std::vector<int>   dist(n+1, -1);
std::vector<bool>  visited(n+1, false);
std::vector<int>   parents(n+1, -1);
```

4) you access arrays without bounds checking. By example:

```
cin >> snode;
dist[snode] = 0;
```

where `snode` is a `int` variable; if you insert a negative value, or a value over `n`, you write `dist` out of its bounds, devastating the memory. This, I suppose, can explain your "bad alloc exception".

Suggestion: use standard containers (again) instead of C-style array and use `at()` (that perform bounds checking) instead `[]`; so

```
cin >> snode;
dist.at(snode) = 0;
```

5) sorry for my bad English (ok, I'm joking: this isn't one of your weak points; this is one of mine).